# Rotation around an arbitrary point using transformation matrix

Tags: algorithm, graphics, matrix, computer-vision, linear-algebra

I want to rotate point around an arbitrary point using transformation matrix.

So the equations are:

```
p'x = cos(theta) * (px-ox) - sin(theta) * (py-oy) + ox
p'y = sin(theta) * (px-ox) + cos(theta) * (py-oy) + oy
```

But I want to rewrite it in form of matrix transforms, it seems like it should be (c=cos(theta),s=sin(theta)):

[image]

By default, the rotation matrix uses the origin point as the center of the rotation. To rotate around an arbitrary point, you have to subtract the distance to the origin using a translation matrix, do the rotation, and then translate back.

If I understand it right first we subtract from original point to make ot (0,0), then rotate around point (0,0) and then add to result point, but I think that 1st and 3rd matrix must be swapped?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely about [math.se].

Comment: @Dukeling I think it's related to computer graphics.

Comment: _"I think that 1st and 3rd matrix must be swapped"_. I think you might be right. The fastest way to find out is probably by experimentation: try it not swapped, then try it swapped, and see which one looks right.

Comment: @Kevin I tried it(I multiply them by hand)but I don't theoretically understand why it works.(I don't understand why matrices should not be swaped)

Comment: Once you've figured out the maths, and you're trying to write the code, *then* it becomes a programming question. Currently all I see is maths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't swap your 1st and 3rd matrix, as you are right-multiplying the point which is a column vector, so the sequence is not left to right, instead it is right to left.

You can easily verify the result by extending the right hand matrix, which will be exact the equations representing p'x and p'y.